# How to debug express router

Tags: node.js, debugging, express

I'm trying to add a module to a huge project, based on another module from the same project.

The client side, in angular, requests an object via

```
$http.get('/foo/var');
```

And the server is registering the routing this way:

```
var express = require('express');
module.exports = function(dependencies) {
    var controller = require('./controller')(dependencies);
    var router = express.Router();
    router.get('/foo/var', controller.getInbox);

    return router;
};
```

Now, this is not working (requesting http://ulr:port/foo/var returns a 404). I'm not asking why does this not work, but why can't I debug it like:

```
var logger = dependencies('logger');//Works OK
var controller = require('./controller')(dependencies);

logger.debug('This string is being printed when registering this module');

var router = express.Router();
router.get('/foo/var', controller.getInbox);

logger.debug(router);//This makes the server crash
return router;
```

So, whenever I try to log the router (both in my dysfunctional router, and the working one I'm basing mine on) the server refuses to launch by throwing this exceptions

```
error: Fatal error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'method' of null
    at Function.proto.handle (/path/to/my/project/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:114:33)
    at router (/path/to/my/project/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:24:12)
    at cb (/path/to/my/project/node_modules/winston/lib/winston/logger.js:206:7)
    at done (/path/to/my/project/node_modules/winston/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:132:19)
    at /path/to/my/project/node_modules/winston/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:32:16
    at emit (/path/to/my/project/node_modules/winston/lib/winston/logger.js:196:7)
    at /path/to/my/project/node_modules/winston/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:122:13
    at _each (/path/to/my/project/node_modules/winston/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:46:13)
    at Object.async.each (/path/to/my/project/node_modules/winston/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:121:9)
    at Logger.log (/path/to/my/project/node_modules/winston/lib/winston/logger.js:214:9)
error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'method' of null
    at Function.proto.handle (/path/to/my/project/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:114:33)
    at router (/path/to/my/project/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:24:12)
    at cb (/path/to/my/project/node_modules/winston/lib/winston/logger.js:206:7)
    at done (/path/to/my/project/node_modules/winston/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:132:19)
    at /path/to/my/project/node_modules/winston/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:32:16
    at emit (/path/to/my/project/node_modules/winston/lib/winston/logger.js:196:7)
    at /path/to/my/project/node_modules/winston/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:122:13
    at _each (/path/to/my/project/node_modules/winston/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:46:13)
    at Object.async.each (/path/to/my/project/node_modules/winston/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:121:9)
    at Logger.log (/path/to/my/project/node_modules/winston/lib/winston/logger.js:214:9)
```

Despite it would be nice to know what am I doing wrong, I'd rather prefer to know what's the proper way to debug this issue

Debugging the module using [@robertklep's indications](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31965124/1430607)

What I can see in the debug is:

```
Wed, 12 Aug 2015 16:22:46 GMT express:router:route new /foo/var
Wed, 12 Aug 2015 16:22:46 GMT express:router:layer new /foo/var
Wed, 12 Aug 2015 16:22:46 GMT express:router:route get /foo/var
```

So it looks like that's the endpoint I want my thing to listen, but it's still not working, I wonder what's layer and route thing, and why route is repeated, though.

I found this module https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-list-routes and I'm testing it.

### [EDIT] Controller code

```
module.exports = function(dependencies) {
    function getInbox() {
        return [
        { date:'31/08/1986', from:"Moi même", to:"Myself", subject:"about"},
        { date:'01/01/1712', from:"Bill Murray", to:"Hulla Kaboolla", subject:"about"}
        ];
    }

    return {
        getInbox: getInbox,
    };
};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is caused by this:

```
> typeof express.Router()
'function'
```

This makes Winston (your logger) think that `router` is a callback function (which it isn't), and calls it with incorrect arguments that make `router` throw an error.

I'm not sure exactly why you want to log `router`, but if you want to debug Express, you can [read this](http://expressjs.com/guide/debugging.html).

Comment: Actually my problem was that this project I'm working on has dozens of routes and prefixes etc... so I needed to know what was the real endpoint being registered to make sure I'm calling the correct one, that's why I wanted to log the router

I added the results of your suggestion to the question

I hope this makes sense. I'm new to express and still have some blurry concepts about it's structure.

Comment: Can you show how you are using your router, exactly? My guess is that you may be using something similar to `app.use('/foo/var', router)`.

Comment: I'm using: 

    `app.use('/', this.api.unifiedinbox);`

the index.js of unifiedinbox contains a module.export for a function that  `return require('./router')(dependencies);`

Comment: @LuisSieira that looks okay. It's not your controller that is generating the 404?

Comment: I added the controller code to the question as well